# I have trouble entering URLs in the address bar when creating routes with vanila javascript

Tags: javascript, routes, single-page-application

I am trying to create routes with vanilla javascript but every time I type a URL in the address bar I get an error saying, 'Cannot GET /about'. I am requesting a link to a tutorial or an answer to this kind of problem since it is my first time doing it with vanilla javascript and I have no clue.

Comment: We don't either, because we have no idea what your code is or what it's trying to do. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: I had no idea where to actually start since I have been using React for routing and I just wanted an overview from someone on how to create routing functionality with vanilla javascript. I saw a couple of tutorials but they were all different. Thanks to @Quentin, I got a decent overview on how to attempt this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking "Vanilla JavaScript" to mean "JavaScript, running in the browser, without the use of third-party libraries":

What you want is not (reasonably) possible.

---

When you type a URL into the address bar, the browser makes an HTTP request to that URL, and the HTTP server for the origin of the URL (i.e. the scheme + hostname + port) is responsible for delivering *something* (typically a webpage) back to the client.

You can't substitute client-side JavaScript for that initial request to the HTTP server.

---

There is an edge case. I think a [progressive web app](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps) can use a [service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) to intercept the request and generate a response internally. This is no good for handling the initial request though since the PWA wouldn't be installed at the time.

---

Generally, when you are writing a single page application you will need two parts for your URL handling.

**The first part** is the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API). This allows you to write JavaScript which tells the browser:

*In response to the click the user just performed, I am going to update the DOM. If you were to visit *this URL* then you would get the same result as the changes I am making to the DOM, so go ahead and update the address bar to represent that*.

It also lets you hook into the browser's back navigation so you can undo those changes if the user click's back.

**The second part** is where you make sure that the server really does deliver the same content for that other URL.

There are three strategies for achieving this:

- Have the server return a more-or-less empty HTML document that checks the URL as it loads and then populates itself entirely with JavaScript. This is a poor approach which might as well just use [hash bangs](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/breakingthewebwithhashbangs).
- Generate all the HTML documents in advance. This is a strategy employed by [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/glossary/static-site-generator/) and [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export). This is very efficient, but doesn't work for frequently updated content.
- Generate the HTML documents on demand with server side code. [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering) can do this too.

You can do this when you write vanilla JavaScript (kinda), but it takes a **lot of work** since you need to write all the code to run on Node.js (where you might not count it as vanilla any more) to generate the HTML documents. I strongly recommend using a framework.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This makes a lot of sense. I use React as my front-end framework and recently was trying to build a dashboard with vanilla javascript and I thought I could implement the routing functionality with vanilla javascript and so I did not have clear code to show and I was trying a bunch of random tutorials. That is why I asked the question without showing any form of code. I found another solution that worked well with express.js earlier, but I wanted a general overview of this attempt from someone who has done or tried it before. Thank you for your response once again.